# How check status of Phone is Landscape or Portrait when Ativity not auto rotation?

Tags: android

Ativity not auto rotation:

```
       <activity
            android:name=".E028"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
```

If i use onConfigurationChanged , it not working:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

How check status of Phone is Landscape or Portrait when Ativity not auto rotation?

I think this case: i must use sensor

My code:

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
            if (orientation != 1) {
                Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                // listImage.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            orientation = 1;
        } else {
            if (orientation != 0) {
                Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
                // listImage.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            orientation = 0;
        }
    }
```

But it working not best,Status of my phone is Portrait: If inclined a little  back , value return is Landscape.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this..

`getResources().getConfiguration()` will return [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

```
if(YourActivity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
{
    // Portrait Mode
} else {
    // Landscape Mode         
}
```

**EDIT**

[Get phone orientation when locked into one orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836003/get-phone-orientation-when-locked-into-one-orientation)

Comment: Do you think, if i set  android:screenOrientation="portrait",It alway return value is portrait?

Comment: How check status of Phone is Landscape or Portrait when Ativity not auto rotation?

Comment: @mum can you refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836003/get-phone-orientation-when-locked-into-one-orientation

Comment: @mum sorry for the late response i also try that ans. that's why. That ans is working correctly check that.

Comment: I use onOrientationChanged get value of  orientation, don't use onSensorChanged has to convert value from SensorEvent to orientation.

Answer (score -1):

From the accepted solution above, I will say that it worked precisely for me EXCEPT I had to change YourActivity.getResources()...blah, blah, blah to  this.getResources()... blah, blah, blah

Comment: Your answer should contain the complete solution, never refer to questions as above (as no one in the longer run will know which question are you referring to) try to be completely clear in your answers.