# Disable drawer when app is in landscape mode

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on one functionality where I want to disable drawer when app is in landscape mode for both iOS & Android. I saw the DrawerView from React-Navigation.

```
render() {
 // some code
    return (
      <DrawerLayout
        ref={(c: *) => {
          this._drawer = c;
        }}
        drawerLockMode={
          (this.props.screenProps && this.props.screenProps.drawerLockMode) ||
          (config && config.drawerLockMode)
        }
      //some code
       >
        <DrawerScreen
          screenProps={this.props.screenProps}
          navigation={this._screenNavigationProp}
        />
      </DrawerLayout>
    );
}
```

Here screenProps is used to handle the lock mode. I can disable the drawer using navigationOptions but I want to disable when user changes the orientation.
One more thing I have used StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator.

Comment: Solved by using changing screenProps on orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

first check this answer for modes [How check status of Phone is Landscape or Portrait when Ativity not auto rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210258/how-check-status-of-phone-is-landscape-or-portrait-when-ativity-not-auto-rotatio/23210290)

then do `drawer.setEnabled(false)` accordingly.

Comment: I used onLayout to detect the orientation. I am not found setEnable for drawer. Let me know If I need to add anything. I am refering  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer